# Handling Data with Jquery and Php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, arrayobject

I'm building a web application. In my app, if user clicks a Search button with two inputs

[image: Search Form]

..... a table with three columns has to be appear as shown with the images.

[image]

To achieve this i'm using jQuery and php. When i'm running a query, retrieving the values and send the array as a json object in php, problem occurs. The Parsed JSON in jquery(in console screen) is as

```
[{"Name":"Dinesh", "Case_Status":"Open"}]
[{"Name":"Dinesh", "Case_Status":"Open"},{"Name":"Greg", "Case_Status":"Open"}]    [{"Name":"Dinesh", "Case_Status":"Open"},{"Name":"Greg", "Case_Status":"Open"},{"Name":"Sulshekharan", "Case_Status":"Open"}]
[{"Name":"Dinesh", "Case_Status":"Open"},{"Name":"Greg", "Case_Status":"Open"},{"Name":"Sulshekharan", "Case_Status":"Open"},{"Name":"Peter", "Case_Status":"Close"}]
```

I have echoed the array in the while loop, so its showing as above..

```
$Update = array();
$Query = "Select.....";
$result = mysql_query($Query,$link);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)or die(mysql_error()))
{
    $Update[] = array('Name' => $row['Name'], 
               'Case_Status' => $row['Case_Status'], 
                'Walk_in_ID' => $row['Walk_in_ID']);    
    echo json_encode($Update);  
}
```

Using the above code, i got following error

```
 [{"Name":"P.Amulya Wilson ","Case_Status":"Open","Walk_in_ID":"2"}]
 [{"Name":"P.Amulya Wilson ","Case_Status":"Open","Walk_in_ID":"2"},
 {"Name":"P.Amulya Wilson","Case_Status":"Open","Walk_in_ID":"6"}] 
 SCRIPT1002: Syntax error 
 WalkinUpdate.js, line 52 character 3 
 (this line 52 is --> var response = JSON.parse(data);)
```

i have also tried the below code but its returning nothing ($Update = "")

```
$Update = array();
$Query = "Select.....";
$result = mysql_query($Query,$link);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)or die(mysql_error()))
{
    $Update[] = array('Name' => $row['Name'], 
               'Case_Status' => $row['Case_Status'], 
                'Walk_in_ID' => $row['Walk_in_ID']);        
}
 echo json_encode($Update);
```

Using the above code, the console looks as shown in the below figure:
[image]

After surfing google and searching in the internet, i have tried the below code also but no use

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)or die(mysql_error()))
{
    $Update[] = array('Name' => $row['Name'], 
         'Case_Status' => $row['Case_Status'], 
         'Walk_in_ID' => $row['Walk_in_ID']);   
    $superUpdate = json_encode($Update[sizeof($Update) - 1]);   
    echo $superUpdate;      
}
```

I have tried mysql_fetch_array also but no use. The jQuery part is as below code

```
$(document).on('submit', '#Update_Form', function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();

    var Update = {};

    Update.EmployeeType = $("#employeeType").val(),
    Update.EmployeeID = $("#employeeID").val();
    console.log(Update);        
    $.post("php/walkin_data_update.php", Update, function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
        var response = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(response);
        console.log(response.length);
        $("#fieldset3").show();
        $("#UpdateForm2").show();
        for(var i=0;i<response.length;i++)
        {
            var j= 1;
            var Name = response[i].Name;
            var Status = response[i].Case_Status;
            $('#statusTable tr').last().after('<tr>
               <td id="statusName'+j+'">'+Name+'</td>
               <td id="statusCase'+j+'">'+Status+'</td>
               <td><button id="View'+j+'">View</button></tr>');
            count++;
            j++;
        }
    });
});
```

if i use console.dir instead of console.log, it shows as below screeshot:

[image]

It's my first time handle with jquery-ajax-php-json in such situation. Please guide me, how to show such json data in the html using jquery, how can i do this??. Sorry for my english, if it not understandable. In advance thank you.

Comment: I'm confused as to where you are finding an error. Your while loop output looks ok, but then you later say that you find $Output as an empty string. It's an array, so I don't see how it can be an empty string.

Comment: also would be helpful to show us the console.log output if your issue is in javascript/JSON parsing. Does the data make it out of php at all? If not, try outputting json_last_error() after your json_encode and see if json is complaining.

Comment: @islanddave Thank you so much for responding. I have already edited my question, please see it once and guide me.

Comment: I don't think you need the square brackets while defining an array.  Try `$Update = array(...)` instead of `$Update[] = array(...)`.  Although I don't think that's whats going wrong here, but it's worth a try.

Comment: @Jordan the brackets are needed to add nested arrays to $Update, that part is fine.

Comment: @Dineshgaru what is the result of the `console.log(data)` just before `var response = JSON.parse(data);`?

Comment: @islanddave If i use echo inside the while loop, the result of console.log(data) is ---> [{"Name":"P.Amulya Wilson ","Case_Status":"Open","Walk_in_ID":"2"}][{"Name":"P.Amulya Wilson ","Case_Status":"Open","Walk_in_ID":"2"},{"Name":"P.Amulya Wilson","Case_Status":"Open","Walk_in_ID":"6"}]

Comment: Don't echo in the while loop. What does console.log show if you move the echo to after the end of while?

Comment: It shows empty space as i attached the image above

Comment: That makes no sense to me. The 'in the while loop' showed the second (and final) loop containing a valid JSON object. That's what should still be there if you pull the echo out of the loop for $Update

Comment: @islanddave Exactly that i believed but the response is different. What to do??

Comment: change that console.log to a console.dir, what do you get now?

Comment: i echoed the response out of the while loop, now its showing same empty space with " ".

Comment: @islanddave Sir, the result screenshot of using console.dir, i have added in my question, please find it.

Comment: No idea. I'm out for the night. Definitely keep the echo out of the while loop, that will produce invalid JSON for jquery (unless there is only 1 row but still bad design). Some things you can try: do php-side logging to see what $Update is before you echo it. If the data seems to go out, comment out all your console.log lines and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to figure it out by myself after several painful hours that i have to just change the php code as below and its working fine at my end now.

```
while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))!== FALSE)
{
    $Update[] = array('Name' => $row['Name'], 
       'Case_Status' => $row['Case_Status'], 
       'Walk_in_ID' => $row['Walk_in_ID']);                 
}
echo json_encode($Update);
```

Thank You for @islanddave for helping me to achieve this.